# Real Time updates with Firebase Real Time Database Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Currently I built a Cricket auction kind of an app with flutter, where in for each bid it will appear as a chat in a chat like screen, I did this with streams with Cloud Firestore, the thing is after a point the number of reads from Cloud Firestore went sky rocketing. I then realized I'm just updating the current players amount ( his bid ). His bid  and the team which is bidding is the only thing that keeps on changing. With firestore I was able to get all these data with streams and display it in the chat screen with ease. Now I want to change it. I am just going to put a Container and display the current bid and the current bidder by storing and retrieving data from RTDB(Firebase Real Time Database). I want to know how to do it, how to be subscribed to Realtime database how to listen to changes in the Real Time database. I surfed a bit and I was not able to find an answer. Is there any way to be subscribed to the Real Time database like firestore streams in flutter ??.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of tutorials out there on how to [create a realtime listener in Flutter with Firebase Realtime Database](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+a+realtime+listener+in+Flutter+with+Firebase+Realtime+Database). The [package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database) itself also comes with an [example](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database#-example-tab-).

If you haven't tried any of those yet, I recommend starting there. If you tried them and got stuck, post back with the [minimal code that anyone can use to reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Realtime Database APIs offer streaming APIs.  You can see in the API documentation for [DocumentReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseReference-class.html) that each of the `on*()` methods return a Stream.

There is plenty of other information out there that can be easily found with a [web search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&channel=tus3&ei=cZH3XrX8KdfC-gSDpquAAQ&q=flutter%20firebase%20realtime%20database%20&oq=flutter%20firebase%20realtime%20database%20&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADIECAAQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgQIABAeOgQIABBHOgQIABBDOgYIABAHEB46CAgAEAgQBxAeUIzhBFjx9QRg_PYEaABwAngBgAGcAYgB6QeSAQM2LjSYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwj1-LO40aLqAhVXoZ4KHQPTChAQ4dUDCAs&uact=5).

Comment: And I want to know about another thing, I know for a fact that RTDB dose'nt have any read write limitations, but when coming to storage in RTDB, say for example I store a data and delete it after a while, will it show any value in the storage ? like you have this amount of data stored out of 1GB quota even if i delete ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  It sounds like you have a new question, so please post that separately, and explain what you're trying to do.